# Passing functions as props to child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Assuming I have a component named `Modal` which I want to reuse across my application and in the meanwhile I also want to dynamically bind functions to its `Yes` button, how can I pass a function to the `@click` event of the `Yes` button in my `Modal` as a prop. For instance:

```
//data tags are used for fast markup here only
<tamplate>
    <div>
        <div :id="`${id}`" data-modal>
           <div data-modal-title>
               {{title}}
           </div>
           <div data-modal-body>
               {{body}}
           </div>
           <div data-modal-footer>
               <button @click="//event to be passed//" data-modal-button-ok>Yes</button>
               <button data-modal-button-cancel>Yes</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       name: 'modal',
       props: [
          'id',
          'title',
          'body',
           // event?
       ]
   }
</script>
```

and when using this modal, how should the event be passed?

```
<Modal id="x" title="y" body="x" //event="????"//></Modal>
```

Comment: If the parent is your presentational component, then you can create bi-directional communication with `emitters`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Would you please provide more description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `$emit` an event (name, say, `yes`) at the modal:

```html
<button @click="$emit('yes')" data-modal-button-ok>Yes</button>
```

Or, use a method:

```html
<button @click="handleYesClick" data-modal-button-ok>Yes</button>
```

```js
methods: {
  handleYesClick() {
    this.$emit('yes');
  }
}
```

And listen to it in the parent using:

```html
<modal ... v-on:yes="someCodeToExecute"></modal>
```

or (shorthand):

```html
<modal ... @yes="someCodeToExecute"></modal>
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('modal',  {
  template: "#modal",
  name: 'modal',
  props: ['id', 'title', 'body']
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    methodAtParentYes() {
      alert('methodAtParentYes!');
    },
    methodAtParentCancel() {
      alert('methodAtParentCancel!');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="modal">
    <div>
        <div :id="`${id}`" data-modal>
           <div data-modal-title>
               {{title}}
           </div>
           <div data-modal-body>
               {{body}}
           </div>
           <div data-modal-footer>
               <button @click="$emit('yes')" data-modal-button-ok>Yes</button>
               <button @click="$emit('cancel')" data-modal-button-cancel>Cancel</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <modal id="1" title="My Title" body="Body" @yes="methodAtParentYes" @cancel="methodAtParentCancel"></modal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this.

---

The first way is you could pass the method down as a prop, just like you would pass anything else and then in the Modal component just call that prop right in the click handler.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
   <Modal id="x" title="y" body="x" :handleYes="handleYes"></Modal>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    handleYes () {
      // do something
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Modal.vue**

```
<button @click="handleYes()">Yes</button>
```

---

The other way is to use `$emit`. So in `Modal.vue` you would define a method to emit an event and then listen for that event in the parent and do call the method there.

**Modal.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click="emitEvent">Yes</button> 
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    emitEvent () {
      this.$emit('userClickedYes')
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
   <Modal id="x" title="y" body="x" @userClickedYes="handleYes"></Modal>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    handleYes () {
      // do something
    }
  }
</script>
```